# Why is this Javascript that writes out a Google Ad not displaying properly on the iPhone?

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova

I have this Javacsript code that checks to see if there is a DIV named "google-ad", and if there is, it writes in a the necessary code to display the Google Ad.

This works great in browsers like Firefox, Chrome, Safari on Mac, and Android.

However, when I bundle this code with [Adobe's Phonegap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/), and deploy it to iPhones, it behaves strangely. It launches a browser window displaying just the Google Ad alone. In order to keep using my app, every time I change a page and a new Google Ad is loaded, I have to close the browser window to get back to the app.

Why is this code launching browser windows outside of my Phonegap app on iPhone?

```
if(document.getElementById("google-ad")
    && document.getElementById("google-ad") !== null
    && document.getElementById("google-ad") !== "undefined")
    {

    if(userStatus.status == 0)
    {
        document.getElementById("centre").style.padding = "137px 0 12px 0";
        document.getElementById("header-container").style.margin = "-138px 0 0 0";
        document.getElementById("header-container").style.height = "132px";
        document.getElementById("header-username").style.top = "52px";

        document.getElementById("google-ad").style.height = "50px";
        document.getElementById("google-ad").style.width = "320px";
        document.getElementById("google-ad").style.backgroundColor = "#f0ebff";
        document.getElementById("google-ad").style.display = "block";

        window["google_ad_client"] = 'ca-pub-0000000000000000';
        window["google_ad_slot"]  = "00000000";
        window["google_ad_width"]  = 320;
        window["google_ad_height"]  = 50;

        window.adcontainer = document.getElementById('google-ad');
        window.adhtml = '';

        function mywrite(html)
        {
            adhtml += html;
            adcontainer.innerHTML = adhtml;
        };

        document.write_ = document.write;
        document.write = mywrite;

        script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src='http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js';
        script.type='text/javascript';
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problom you are facing is becuase google adsens is using iframe see in show_ads.js

```
e=["<iframe"],d;for(d in a)a.hasOwnProperty(d)&&ka(e,d+"="+a[d]);e.push('style="left:0;position:absolute;top:0;"')
```

and when that happens in phonegap(generally webview) it will open new page to show it.
there are some ways to turn around but best way i could suggest is using google offical adsense [sdk](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/) for moile :

```
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/
```

it is native but you could easily connect it to you html app with simple plugin(i could help you with that if you want)

the thing you are trying to do now i think cause your app to be rejected by apple so use google official sdk.